# Can I cut out the string in the Django template?

Tags: python, django

This is my code in templates:

```
{% for wine_con in data.winry_consult %}
    <li><a href="/article_list_content-{{win_con.id}}/"><p>{{ win_con.content }}</p><i class="font">&#xe6aa;</i></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I found the `win_con.content` is too long for my website, I only want 5 count characters, how can I cut out the `win_con.content` in template?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter:

```
<li><a href="/article_list_content-{{win_con.id}}/"><p>{{ win_con.content|slice:":5" }}</p><i class="font">&#xe6aa;</i></a></li>
```

Comment: This is a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

Comment: how to add '...' triple dots if it is sliced otherwise we wont add '...' at the end?

Comment: @Rahul maybe you are looking for `truncatechars` ? look at Bear Brown's answer

Answer (score 13):

you may use built-in filter [truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

```
{{ win_con.content|truncatechars:5 }}
```

Comment: Truncate automatically appends an ellipsis which doesn't appear to be desired here.

Comment: but it may be better for usability, i think so

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars  should help

```
{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To cut specific characters do you could use 'cut' which is also part of django template builtins

for example if

```
{{ file.pdf.name}}
```

gives 'store/pdfs/verma2010.pdf'

```
{{ file.pdf.name | cut:'store/pdfs/'}}
```

Would give  'verma2010.pdf'